# Where to ask a question about compression?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about compression and I'm unsure where to ask the question because I couldn't find any sites where this question would fit according to the Help Center.

The question:

***Is there a lower bound of how much compression can be done on data?***

---

I thought that mathSE might be suited since there might be a mathematical proof that explains i.e. why any data can't be compressed to less than 50% of it's original size (even if we don't have such a compression algorithm yet).

Comment: I'm sorry but the link of which this question is apparently a duplicate of doesn't have any references for questions about compression, so which site should I post this question to?

Comment: Questions about compression are ultimately questions about programming algorithms. So one of those sites is appropriate. You're supposed to apply your particular needs to the criteria outlined on that Q&A to find out what site to post on.

Comment: Would the lower bound not be zero?